# find and replace multiple lines of string using sed

Tags: bash, sed, gnu-sed

I have an input file containing the following numbers

```
-45.0005
-43.0022
-41.002
.
.
.
```

I have a target txt file

```
line:12 Angle=30
line:42 Angle=60
line:72 Angle=90
.
.
.
```

Using sed I want to replace the first instance of Angle entry in the target file with the first entry from the input file, the second entry of Angle with the second entry of the input file so and so forth...

Expected output:

```
line:12 Angle=-45.005
line:42 Angle=-43.002
line:72 Angle=-41.002
.
.
.
```

This is what I have managed to write but I am not getting the expected output

```
a=`head -1 temp.txt`
#echo $a
sed  -i "12s/Angle = .*/Angle = $a/g" $procfile
for i in {2..41..1}; do
        for j in {42..1212..30}; do
                c=$(( $i - 1 ))
                #echo "this is the value of c: $c"
                b=`head -$i temp.txt | tail -$c`
                #echo "This is the value of b: $b"
                sed  -i "$js/Angle = .*/Angle = $b/g" $procfile 2> /dev/null
        done
done
```

Could you help me improve the script?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how awk could be used? I can imagine using the NR operator, but not sure of the best way...

Comment: `Angle entry in the target file with the first entry from the input file` Then why in the output you have `line:12 Angle=-45.005` and not `line:12 Angle=-45.0005` ? And `-43.002` not `-43.0022`?

Comment: check if my answer fits your problem.

Comment: A one-liner would do it: `paste target.txt input.txt | sed 's/=.*\t/=/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create an iterator `i` and then use it in `sed` to perform substitution in each line.

```
i=0; 
while read -r line; do 
   i=$((i+1)); 
   sed -i "${i}s/Angle=.*/Angle=${line}/g" $procfile; 
done < temp.txt
```

Comment: ```while read -r file; do ``` is file a variable?. Also note that occurrence of string "Angle" occurs every 30 lines starting from line 12

Comment: I changed `file` to `line` as it was semantically incorrect - and yes, it's a variable. So, use `i=11` and put `i=$((i+30)); `. This will only save time, since the code will work as-is, too.

Comment: thanks... it almost works... however the the replacement starts at line 42 instead of line 12.

Comment: Change the order. First apply `sed` and after the `i=$((i+30)); `

Comment: I came close to solving it as well!

```
for i in {1..41..1};do
        a=`head -$i temp.txt | tail -1`
        for j in {12..1212..30}; do
                sed -i "${j}s/Angle = .*/Angle = $a/g" foo.txt
        done
done
```
The reason that it doesnt work is because I dont how to increment two vars in a single for loop with different step sizes.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you want to `paste` files - marge files line by line. Then replace the field with a regex for example.

```
paste target_file input_file | sed 's/\(Angle=\)[^\t]*\t/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

pr might help here, please try this:

```
pr -m -t target input | sed -r 's/(Angle=)[^\s]+\s+/\1/'
```

Please note - this works for your first two showed files, your code assumes some different input - e.g. spaces around "=".

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Angle=/R inputFile' targetFile | sed '/Angle=/{N;s/=.*\n/=/}'
```

In the first sed invocation append the input line.

In the second sed invocation remove the original `angle` and the newline delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to come up with this solution

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=$1
cp $infile ORIG_${infile}
grep "Angle = " $infile | sed 's/Angle = //g' | sort -n > temp.txt

iMax=`cat temp.txt | wc -l`
jMax=`grep -n "Angle = " $infile | tail -1 | sed 's/:.*//g'`

for ((i=1,j=12; i<=${iMax} && j<=${jMax};i+=1,j+=30));do
        a=`head -$i temp.txt | tail -1`
        sed -i "${j}s/Angle = .*/Angle = $a/g" $infile
done
rm temp.txt
```

Many thanks to [william pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) for clarifying the syntax for incrementing var counts in bash.